# How can I run multiple network interfaces on a k8s node?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Running Openshift 4.1 on K8s v1.13.4. I'm trying to add a second network (for NFS storage) to my compute nodes, and as soon as I do, the node stops reporting `NodeReady`.

See below logs from kubelet. Completely lost.. How can I add another interface to my nodes?

v1.13.4

```
FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NodeReady' Node compute-0 status is now: NodeReady
Jun 26 05:41:22 compute-0 hyperkube[923]: E0626 05:41:22.367174     923 kubelet_node_status.go:380] Error updating node status, will retry: failed to patch status "{\"status\":{\"$setElementOrder/addresses\":[{\"type\":\"ExternalIP\"},{\"type\":\"InternalIP\"},{\"type\":\"ExternalIP\"},{\"type\":\"InternalIP\"},{\"type\":\"Hostname\"}],\"$setElementOrder/conditions\":[{\"type\":\"MemoryPressure\"},{\"type\":\"Dis

...

Jun 26 05:41:22 compute-0 hyperkube[923]: [map[address:10.90.49.111 type:ExternalIP] map[type:ExternalIP address:10.90.51.94] map[address:10.90.49.111 type:InternalIP] map[address:10.90.51.94 type:InternalIP]]
Jun 26 05:41:22 compute-0 hyperkube[923]:  doesn't match $setElementOrder list:
```

Comment: The question is bit unclear to me. Could you clarify that you want to have two different virtual network cards on a VM and then pass this information to PODs?

Comment: Correct. The intent was to "plug in" a second network card. Doing this broke node communication. Resolution was below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolution was to delete node from cluster `kubectl delete node compute-0`, reboot it, and let ignition rejoin it to the cluster.

This is a known bug